# Cannot tap a table cell in Xcode UI testing

Tags: tableview, xcode-ui-testing

I am writing Xcode UI test cases for a tableview. My code (Objective-C) is something like this

```
XCUIElement *elementCell = app.cells[@"AccessibilityIdentifierOfTheCell"];
XCTAssertTrue(elementCell.exists); // this assert passed
[elementCell tap]; // !!!??? crashed here
```

The testing crashes at the "tap" method.

I also tried Xcode's "Recode UI Test" [image] to see how Xcode would catch the "tapping" behaviour in UI testing but, unfortunately, when I tapped on the cell the testing crashed as well and Xcode popped up this:
[image]

I got stuck here for quite a while and it will be highly appreciated if anyone can help me out.

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36597862/xcode-timestamped-event-matching-error-failed-to-find-matching-element

Answer (score 1):

Right after the question was posted I went back and tried again and, weirdly, it worked. I changed nothing. It may be that Xcode UI testing functionality is not steady yet.

Sorry for that.