# Is there a way to determine which view invoked "Timestamped Event Matching Error"

Tags: xcode-ui-testing, xcode-storyboard, xcode10

The "Timestamped Event Matching Error" is common one regarding Xcode Testing as seen from popular StackOverflow questions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36616891/timestamped-event-matching-error-failed-to-find-matching-element) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36597862/xcode-timestamped-event-matching-error-failed-to-find-matching-element) and the concensus to solve it seems to be:

*Enable the accessibility Boolean, and supply the accessessibilityLabel ,accessibilityIdentifier properties with strings either programmatically, in Xcode identity inspector or by adding run time attributes in the identity inspector*

My question: is there a way to determine what Object is invoking the Error e.g. by displaying the ObjectID which would make it searchable and help narrow debugging efforts beyond "enable for every conceivable view both in storyboard and programmatically".

Comment: I never really found a solution to this beyond -- deleting Derived Data & Clean & Often restarting Xcode before running Tests. Switching between Targets is still dodgy in Xcode